# Creating catalog of ModelBuilder models?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I have to create a catalog with several models that was made with ModelBuilder.

Do you know a way to record basic information of a model and do it several times. i.e. (Path, Variables, elapsed time)?

Something similar to the report generated in ModelBuilder but without the necessity of opening the model because there are a lot of models.